# Failed to run task sequence - 80004005. DNS working though

Tags: windows, sccm

I seem to be getting a fairly common generic error but with possibly with a slight difference then some of the other problems/answers I have seen.  Generally it looks like this is a DNS issue but I am not sure in my case.

Let me 1st describe my infrastructure and what I am trying to accomplish.  We use PKI on the main MPs/DPs.  I have another DP that I will use for OSD content that won’t use PKI.  I am 1st attempting to use boot media, vs PXE, to image a computer.  I have distributed the content to the DP, created a boot media USB and everything looks good there as far as I can tell.  My boot media selects the PKI MP and we have created the client cert and I direct it to the non-http DP.  The process seems to accept the certificate and the boot media creation completes.  Next boot off the media on the computer and drop into Windows PE where I can manually enter the IP information.  When I click next the process fails.

Error:
Failed to Run Task Sequence
An error occurred while retrieving policy for this computer (0x80004005).

So starting some of the troubleshooting I F8.
-Can I ping the SCCM site servers?  Yes, I can ping, both short and FQDN, the primary, MP, DP.
Looking at the SMSTSLog I see the following lines/errors.
1)Failed to open PXE registry key.  Not a PXE boot.
2)Failed to find the source drive where WinPE was booted from
But then the next line is:  Executing from Media WinPE
These 2 are at the top of the log and the process seems to continue on with the IP and variable information.  These are the lines of information later in the log with the error(s):
-CLibSMSMessageWinHTTPTransport::Send:URL: (my MP)
-In SSL, but with no client cert
-Error.  Received 0x80072ee7 from WinHttpSendRequest.
-Hr,HRESULT=80072ee7
-sending with winhttp failed, 80072ee7
-m_pHttp Transport -> (etc….)
-MPKeyInformation.RequestMPKeyInformationForMedia
-Failed to get information of MP: https//(my MP)

So I am wondering where I start.  I don’t see that unknown host line that seems to indicate that it is a DNS issue.  I see some stuff about the in SSL but with no cert.  Does this mean that the cert we had to create isn’t working correctly?  We pretty much followed http://www.jamesbannanit.com/2012/05/how-to-build-and-capture-in-configuration-manager-2012-using-https/
I have also looked through this http://blogs.technet.com/b/configurationmgr/archive/2009/07/27/a-step-by-step-for-using-osd-through-system-center-configuration-manager-2007.aspx
And I have pretty much everything done there except a network access account.  Looking at my settings I am set to, “Use the computer account of the Configuration Manager client”  However, my computer I am trying to image is a “WORKGROUP” and not joining the domain.  But.. am I really getting that far in the process?  Would I be failing to get policy because of this or does this just come into play when I try to get the OS from the DP?

Comment: Have you tried deleting that computer from sccm?